# OpenGL - Help restricting curves to never go out of bounds

Tags: c++, opengl, bezier, curves

I have the following program to draw arcs using Bézier Curves:

```
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/openglut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


std::ofstream nul("/dev/null");
std::ostream * err=&std::cerr;

class Point {
public:
int _id;
GLfloat _x;
GLfloat _y;
GLfloat _z;

Point(int id, GLfloat x, GLfloat y, GLfloat z) :
    _id(id),
    _x(x),
    _y(y),
    _z(z) {
}

void PrintPoint() {
    printf("Point %d = <%f, %f, %f>\n", _id, _x, _y, _z);
}
};

Point getControl(Point a, Point b){

if(a._x < b._x && a._y < b._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2)+(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), ((a._y+b._y)/2)-(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), 0.0);
    return ctrl;
} else if(a._x < b._x && a._y > b._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2)+(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), ((a._y+b._y)/2)-(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), 0.0);
    return ctrl;
} else if(b._x < a._x && b._y < a._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2)+(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), ((a._y+b._y)/2)-(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), 0.0);
    return ctrl;
} else if(b._x < a._x && b._y > a._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2)+(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), ((a._y+b._y)/2)-(0.25*(b._x-a._x)), 0.0);
    return ctrl;
} else if(a._x == b._x && a._y != b._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2) + (0.25*a._x), (a._y+b._y)/2, 0.0);
    return ctrl;
} else if(a._x != b._x && a._y == b._y){
    Point ctrl(10, ((a._x+b._x)/2), ((a._y+b._y)/2) + (0.25*a._y), 0.0);
    return ctrl;
}
return a;
}

GLfloat bezierP(float t, GLfloat P0, GLfloat P1, GLfloat P2, GLfloat P3) {
GLfloat point = (pow((1-t), 3.0) * P0) +
    (3 * pow((1-t),2) * t * P1) +
    (3 * (1-t) * t * t * P2) +
    (pow(t, 3) * P3);
return point;
}

void drawBezierArc(Point start, Point end){

Point ctrl = getControl(start, end);
start.PrintPoint();
end.PrintPoint();
ctrl.PrintPoint();

int i;

glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    int t = 60;
    for (i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
        float pos = (float) i / (float) t;
        GLfloat x = bezierP(pos, start._x, ctrl._x, ctrl._x, end._x);
        GLfloat y = bezierP(pos, start._y, ctrl._y, ctrl._y, end._y);
        GLfloat z = bezierP(pos, start._z, ctrl._z, ctrl._z, end._z);

        glVertex3f(x, y, z);
    }
glEnd();

glFlush();
}

void display(void) {

Point start1(0, 6, -2, 0);
Point end1(0, 6, 4, 0);

Point start2(0, 0, 2, 0);
Point end2(0, 4, 3, 0);

Point start3(0, -2, 0, 0);
Point end3(0, 1, 0, 0);

Point start4(0, -4, 3, 0);
Point end4(0, -4, -2, 0);

drawBezierArc(start1, end1);
drawBezierArc(start2, end2);
drawBezierArc(start3, end3);
drawBezierArc(start4, end4);

glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h) {
glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

if (w <= h) {
    glOrtho(-5.0, 5.0, -5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, 5.0*(GLfloat)h/(GLfloat)w, -5.0, 5.0);
} else {
    glOrtho(-5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, 5.0*(GLfloat)w/(GLfloat)h, -5.0, 5.0, -5.0, 5.0);
}

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize (640, 480);
glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

[image: Problem]

The curves here are made with Bézier Curves, so each curve is a series of many straight lines that make it look like a arc/curve. As you can see by the arc on the far right, it goes beyond the windows bounds. When something like this happens, I would like to restrict it and keep the exceeding lines inside the window (or at least to go along the window's edge).

My go at this problem was to subtract the distance from which the exceeding points are from the windows edge but this did not seem to work. It was something like this:

```
double dist = exceedingPoint - boundaryValue;
exceedingPoint = exceedingPoint - dist;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more detail? Screenshots? What kind of code you have in mind? Give us **something** to work off, you also aren't going to find many people taking the time out to download any dependencies for your program and build it themselves, so explain it as if we *cannot* run the program ourselves

Comment: Thank you for correcting my bad post. I've added more details, code and an image.

Comment: do you specifically control of a specific line, or do you just want the all of the lines inside the screen?

Comment: A Bézier curve is bounded by the convex hull of it's control points. So a rectangle that contains all the control points will completely contain the curve. You can subdivide a Bezier curve into two self-contained Bezier curves, and apply this process recursively.

Comment: Well as my answer suggests, couldn't you just apply a `glTranslatef` before the draw to fix the out of bounds?

Comment: @Gmercer015 hum... yes I could and I guess it would work but that would change the start and end points coordinates and I can't do that (this is just some simplified code to show this problem from a much bigger project)

That does solve the problem for that particular arc, but it also shitfts everything else to the left. 

Would it be possible to change the control point - given the arc exceeds the world coordinates - of the Bézier Curve to reduce the curvature of the arc?

Comment: @BrettHale, could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: If you write your own shaders, this could be done pretty easily. After you apply your regular transform, move points outside the view volume to the boundary of the view volume. If you want to stick to the fixed pipeline, I can't think of an elegant way to do what you want. You'll probably have to manipulate the points on the CPU before rendering. I certainly recommend the shader path, it will give you a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I do not write my own shaders as I'm only a beginner OpenGL user

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this really qualifies as an OpenGL question - but more a matter of problem solving.

Depending upon what you want (and from looking at your comments above) -

1) You could evaluate the size of your bézier curve (find out how big a rectangle would be, if it contained the curve), and then see if it's going to exceed the window size.  Resize or move the curve to fit it back in.

2) Evaluate the points as you are calculating them.  If they appear to be going outside of the window, then set the coordinate of the point to the window's edge.

3) Learn GLSL and figure out how a Vertex Shader could also be capable of doing #2.

Basically, there's a lot of stuff you can do. Try again!

Comment: I have tried option 2 and it seems simple enough and easy to get to work, but it didnt. I am going to try again anyway

Comment: If your coordinate space is set up properly (lets say - one 'unit' in your application == one pixel in your window) then #2 ought to be easy.  Try checking to see if you can simply render a straight line across the edge of your window, and then go from there.